# Is it recommended to change the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to 'CHAR' from BYTE in a live database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Whould it be a good idea to change the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` in a live database.
The database character set uses a multibyte character encoding scheme. Due to this the application gets random errors which cannot be recreated. In most occations the `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` is raised. So to fix this we plan to change the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter value. For the application the recommended `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` setting was `CHAR` and it was not set to that value when the DB instance was created.
My question is, Will just changing the value to `CHAR` help? or will a new DB instance created with `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR'` and exporting the old DB and importing it to the new DB help?

Answer (score 2):

`NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` enables you to create `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` columns using either byte or character length semantics. 
**Existing columns are not affected.**
It means there is no risk for existing data.

However  the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter set to `CHAR` may cause many existing installation scripts to unexpectedly create columns with character length semantics, resulting in runtime errors, including buffer overflows.
To workaround it you need to make sure you set `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE` when running any Oracle "internal" scripts like patches, upgrades, etc..

Comment: does setting the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR while installing a oracle patch or upgrade effect the whole database( including the old data/existing instalattion scripts too) or only the new data??
I want to be able to change the setting so it will effect existing data too?

Comment: Change of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to CHAR will affect only new operations. I think you need to figure out what the source of the issue is. Is it caused by a) too small columns in existing tables or  b) too small size of variables in your application scripts? In case it's a) then changing of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS will not help. However for b) it may help.

Comment: What if I create anew data base instance with NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to CHAR. Export the old database and import it to the newly created DB. Will it change all the old object (columns and etc.) to CHAR too??

Comment: I have never tried but i am 99% sure that all your object will stay the same. If they would have changed because of the setting, it means bug.

Answer (score 0):

In this article, I provide examples of PL/SQL buffer overflow and table insert errors when character length semantics are set to BYTE. In these examples, changing to CHAR semantics clears the error.

Here is a buffer overflow, and fix.

```
show parameter nls_length_semantics;
NAME                 TYPE   VALUE 
-------------------- ------ ----- 
nls_length_semantics string BYTE 

declare
    l_name varchar2(100) := 'What Are Em Dashes ( — ) And How Do You Use Them?';
    l_sub varchar2(100);
    l_buf varchar2(30);
begin
    l_sub := substr(l_name, 1, 30);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sub);
    dbms_output.put_line('lengthb: ' || lengthb(l_sub));
    l_buf := l_sub;
end;
/
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

alter session set nls_length_semantics=char;
Session altered.

What Are Em Dashes ( — ) And H
lengthb: 32
```

Here is a column insert error and fix:

```
show parameter nls_length_semantics;
NAME                 TYPE   VALUE 
-------------------- ------ ----- 
nls_length_semantics string BYTE 

create table cathedrals(
   name  varchar2(30)
);
Table CATHEDRALS created.

insert into cathedrals (name) values (q'{Kölner Dom St. Peter und Maria}');
ORA-12899: value too large for column "USR"."CATHEDRALS"."NAME" (actual: 31, maximum: 30)

alter table cathedrals modify name varchar2(30 char);
Table CATHEDRALS altered.

insert into cathedrals (name) values (q'{Kölner Dom St. Peter und Maria}');
1 row inserted.
```

Even then, you are still vulnerable to runtime buffer overflows.

```
show parameter nls_length_semantics;
NAME                 TYPE   VALUE 
-------------------- ------ ----- 
nls_length_semantics string BYTE  
declare
  l_name varchar2(30);
begin
  select name into l_name from cathedrals;
end;
/
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
alter session set nls_length_semantics=char;
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Oracle claims that setting nls_length_semantics to BYTE can lead to buffer overflows. In fact, I have provided three examples where changing nls_length_semantics to CHAR is the fix for such errors!

Parameter nls_length_semantics was introduced in Oracle 9i. Starting in 12c, the manual was revised to include the warning about buffer overflows. This warning has repeated in the blogs, including Don Burleson's.

If you do not set nls_length_semantics to CHAR at the instance level, but your application could store multibyte characters, then ensure that when you create your tables to explicitly declare CHAR for every column.

Otherwise, what can happen over the years is that as foreign language names (street, city, university, etc.) get added to your application, the same error appears in different places.

You are better off setting nls_length_semantics in your tables to CHAR early in the application life cycle.

The original poster asks: "Would it be a good idea to change the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS in a live database?" Do two things:

1. Alter all character columns to CHAR semantics.
2. Change the instance nls_length_semantics to CHAR.

Comment: How does changing the instance semantics to CHAR help? The session-scoped semantics is still BYTE and should override it. I can't figure out how to permanently change the session scope to CHAR.